# Load entire table into cache Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to load an entire table into cache on Grails startup?

For example I have a 2 tables with 5000 records each that is used as static read only data. This data is the most hard hit though since all information on other tables is derived from this read-only table.

I know grails has a cache usage scenario but this infomation is constantly being evicted from the cache after a short amount of time and it also only gets re-cached on the next request.

Basically trying to reduce response times by not having to access the database for this static data.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the cache behavior with ehcache.xml. If you don't have one the caches are configured with default values but if you do it's used instead. Put it in `grails-app/conf` and it will be copied to the classpath.

Assuming your domain class is `com.yourcompany.yourapp.YourDomainClass`, you can specify the number of elements to cache and set eternal = true so they aren't discarded:

```
<ehcache>

   <diskStore path='java.io.tmpdir' />

   <defaultCache
      maxElementsInMemory='10000'
      eternal='false'
      timeToIdleSeconds='120'
      timeToLiveSeconds='120'
      overflowToDisk='true'
      maxElementsOnDisk='10000000'
      diskPersistent='false'
      diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds='120'
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy='LRU'
   />

   <cache name='com.yourcompany.yourapp.YourDomainClass'
      maxElementsInMemory='10000'
      eternal='true'
      overflowToDisk='false'
   />

   <!-- hibernate stuff -->
   <cache name='org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache'
      maxElementsInMemory='50'
      eternal='false'
      timeToLiveSeconds='120'
      maxElementsOnDisk='0'
   />

   <cache
      name='org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache'
      maxElementsInMemory='5000'
      eternal='true'
      maxElementsOnDisk='0'
   />

</ehcache>
```

For more information about how to configure `ehcache.xml` see http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml which has a lot of documentation in the comments.

Having done that, your `BootStrap.groovy` should look something like this:

```
import com.yourcompany.yourapp.YourDomainClass

class BootStrap {

   def init = { servletContext ->
      def ids = YourDomainClass.executeQuery('select id from YourDomainClass')
      for (id in ids) {
         YourDomainClass.get(id)
      }
   }
}
```

Having called `get()` for each instance, future calls to `get()` will use the 2nd-level cache.

Comment: Could the code in `Bootstrap.groovy` be replaced with `YourDomainClass.list()` ?